# Is it possible to filter all graphical applications to install or remove them using some graphical software manager?

Tags: apt, software-installation, gui, .desktop, mate

I have a computer which was updated from 10.04 LTS step-by-step to the latest Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version. This means that I have a long list of applications - both graphical and terminal-based.

If I visit the `/usr/share/applications` folder using Caja file-manager I see very long list of icons (about 400). And as the result they create long lists in the categories of *Applications* menu on MATE Panel.

How can I remove some of such graphical applications using some kind of graphical software manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I have found the [Apper](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/apper) application which has the needed options.

Use the following sequence:

1. Open Apper
2. In the *Lists* section select Installed Software
3. In the right open *Filters* drop-down check the *Only Show Applications* option
4. Enjoy the list of graphical applications

   [image: Apper with Show Only Applications filter enabled]
5. Choose applications to remove by pressing *Remove* button in the *Actions* column
6. Click *Apply* to simulate the removal, carefully review the list of deb-package names and if you are sure, then proceed with next step
7. Finally click *Continue* to start real removal process of related deb-packages

---

Notes:

1. some applications are not shown in the above list, but their quantity is small.
2. to install the graphical application one can use the *Filters* → *Installed* → *Only available* with checked *Only Show Applications*.
3. to search for graphical application by its description one should select *Find by description* in the right of text field and then use the *Filters* → *Installed* → *Only available* with checked *Only Show Applications*.

Comment: Does this procedure remove (i.e. uninstall) the applications or does it only remove the `.desktop` files? Are _all_ installed graphical applications listed there or only ones installed via apt/snap/flatpak?

Comment: Apper removes (uninstalls) the corresponding deb-packages. And do it great! It does not know about snaps and flatpaks.